# Pointwise vs. pairwise Learning-to-rank on DATA WITH BINARY RELEVANCE VALUES

Tags: ranking, information-retrieval, pairwise

I have two question about the differences between pointwise and pairwise learning-to-rank algorithms on DATA WITH BINARY RELEVANCE VALUES (0s and 1s). Suppose the loss function for a pairwise algorithm calculates the number of times an entry with label 0 gets ranked before an entry with label 1, and that for a pointwise algorithm calculates the overall differences between the estimated relevance values and the actual relevance values.

So my questions are: 1) theoretically, will the two groups of algorithms perform significantly differently? 2) will a pairwise algorithm degrade to pointwise algorithm in such settings?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In point wise estimation the errors across rows in your data (rows with items and users, you want to rank items within each user/query) are assumed to be independent sort of like normally distributed errors. Whereas in pair wise evaluation the algorithm loss function often used is cross entropy - a relative measure of accurately classifying 1's as 1's and 0's as 0s in each pair (with information - i.e. one of the item is better than other within the pair).

So changes are that the pair wise is likely to learn better than point-wise.

Only exception I could see is a business scenario when users click items without evaluating/comparing items from one another per-say. This is highly unlikely though.